# Download a file from server in angular

Tags: angular

How to do download a file in angular which is already existing in the server. A PDF file is generated in the server and stored in the server itself in a memory location. I want to download that file. In the API call I get the path of the file. From that path how can I download the file?

Comment: Please make some attempts before posting the question. There is a first link in Google which gives you a sample: https://www.roytuts.com/download-file-from-server-using-angular/

Answer (score 0):

you need something like this:

```
this._api.getPDF()
  .subscribe(res => {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = res;
    link.download = `filename.pdf`;
    link.click();
  },
  err => {
    // Handle error message
  });
```